# CSS list decoration

Tags: css, list

I've hided list decoration, because I'm making dropdown lists. But the issue that it still take empty spase where it was dot before, how may I solve it?

I've delite decoration. but issue is empty spase before li

```
li {
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most user agent style sheets add default `padding` or `margin` to ordered and unordered lists. You'll have to remove that too:

```css
ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

li {
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

For future reference, you can look at the elements in your page using your browser's developer tools (F12 by default) to see what CSS is being applied to them:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```css
ul {
  display: initial;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```